# Apache can't host ASP.NET Core app using ProxyPass

Tags: apache, asp.net-core, proxy, configuration, debian

I want my ASP.NET Core app to be hosted through Apache, so that port `80` redirects to port `5000`, or `5001` for https. (my local IP is 192.168.1.250 for context in results)

I have tried the following configs with varying results:

- Proxy to `http://127.0.0.1:5000/`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:5000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:5000/
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/myapp.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/myapp.log common
</VirtualHost>
```

Will redirect me to port 5001, but I get this in Chrome:

```
This site can’t be reached: 192.168.1.250 refused to connect.
Try:

Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

---

- Proxy to `https://127.0.0.1:5001/`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / https://127.0.0.1:5001/
    ProxyPassReverse / https://127.0.0.1:5001/
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/myapp.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/myapp.log common
</VirtualHost>
```

This config gives me a `500 Internal Server Error`:

```
Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at [no address given] to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Apache/2.4.25 (Debian) Server at 192.168.1.250 Port 80
```

---

- Proxy to `http://127.0.0.1:5001/`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:5001/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:5001/
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/myapp.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/myapp.log common
</VirtualHost>
```

This config gives me a `502 Proxy Error`:

```
Proxy Error
The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server.
The proxy server could not handle the request

Reason: Error reading from remote server

Apache/2.4.25 (Debian) Server at 192.168.1.250 Port 80
```

Any ideas on a config that could work?

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if you resolved this yet but I have a similar problem with dotNet Core 5.0 on Ubuntu/Apache.

I resolved it (kinda) after reading this post: [.NET Core 3.1 API - 307 Temporary Redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61906760/net-core-3-1-api-307-temporary-redirect)

Basically remove the **app.UseHttpsRedirection();** line in your app so it now runs only on http://localhost:5000/

Now Apache is not trying to proxy to your SSL site but your standard site on port 5000. Since it's on 127.0.0.1 (I believe) that should be secure enough (but happy to stand corrected on this...)

Share