# 403 Forbidden In Asp.Net Core app with Apache

Tags: apache, asp.net-core, centos7, asp.net-core-3.1, kestrel-http-server

I'm new with .Net Core and Linux but I'm trying to deploy my MVC app(working well on windows) to Centos with Apache as Reverse Proxy.

For now my app is running(as a Kestrel service) and here is Apache virtual host configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:*>
    RequestHeader set "X-Forwarded-Proto" expr=$scheme
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:5000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:5000/
    ServerName www.my-domain.com
    ServerAlias *.my-domain.com
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}creditselection-error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}creaditselection-access.log common
</VirtualHost>
```

But when I'm trying to access [www.my-domain.com](http://www.my-domain.com) from browser I'm getting default Centos page with 403 Forbidden status.

Also if I run curl command `curl --dump-header - http://localhost:5000` on the server I'm getting this:

```
HTTP/1.1 307 Temporary Redirect
Date: Mon, 28 Dec 2020 17:53:36 GMT
Server: Kestrel
Content-Length: 0
Location: https://localhost:5001/
```

And `curl --dump-header - https://localhost:5001` returns:

```
curl: (60) Issuer certificate is invalid.
More details here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl performs SSL certificate verification by default, using a "bundle"
 of Certificate Authority (CA) public keys (CA certs). If the default
 bundle file isn't adequate, you can specify an alternate file
 using the --cacert option.
If this HTTPS server uses a certificate signed by a CA represented in
 the bundle, the certificate verification probably failed due to a
 problem with the certificate (it might be expired, or the name might
 not match the domain name in the URL).
If you'd like to turn off curl's verification of the certificate, use
 the -k (or --insecure) option.
```

Is it possible that I'm getting 403 in browser because I have no SSL configured yet?

How should I configure my app to get it working well?

Answer (score 0):

Check out this post:
[.NET Core 3.1 API - 307 Temporary Redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61906760/net-core-3-1-api-307-temporary-redirect)

Basically, remove the `app.UseHttpsRedirection();` line in your app so that it now runs only on `http://localhost:5000/`.

After that, Apache should match your "website" with this request via the config file.